# Finding all instances of global data in a binary

Tags: c++, dll, static, global

What's a good way to find all instances of static data in a binary? I'm fixing up luacom (a dll package for lua) to be thread safe, and would like to determine if I've found all instances of global data that would be affected by concurrency.

Are there any good tools out there to figure this out? Any functionality in VC 2008?

Comment: You are aware that you would have to check for *static* data just as well? As in, class variables and the like?

Comment: Yes, that as well! I was wondering if there are binary tools (e.g. dumpbin) that would display symbols for static data in a compiled, debug binary. Then I could grep around for those.

Comment: None that I know of. Grepping for "static" gives you the class variables. As for globals, I could probably patch together some pipe chain with find, nm, c++filt and grep or something, but only for ELF files since I don't know much about the PE object format...